# Whats the best way here to show ajax gif indicator while ng-view is loading?

Tags: angularjs

I have defined ng-view like this

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

and here is my router

```
$routeProvider

.when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/MY/home/home',
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.setActiveMenuMod('my-mod');
    }
})
.when('/users', {
    templateUrl: '/MY/system/users',
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.setActiveMenuMod('my-mod');
    }
})
```

What would be the best approach here to some  only when one of the above configured router's ajax is called? Why in this huge library angularJS there is no simple solution to show ajax indicator while the content is loading in ng-view...
here is my approach

```
$scope.isViewLoading = false;
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(a,b,c) {
    if(b.$$route.templateUrl)
        $scope.isViewLoading = true;
});
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(a,b,c) {
    if(b.$$route.templateUrl)
        $scope.isViewLoading = false;
});
```

and html

```
<div class="ajax-ngview" ng-show="isViewLoading"></div>
<div ng-hide="isViewLoading" ng-view></div>
```

Comment: How about creating a `ng-view-is-loaded` attribute directive? The directive would check if any children exist inside of the `ng-view` and apply a `.loading` class until it *does* have children. Maybe the `.loading` class sets the `background-image` of the div to `loading.gif`